# Trying to create new dictionaries through iteration

Tags: python

I'm not even able to properly search google for it, but here goes:

```
a = {}
b = {}
c = [a, b]
for d in c:
    d['ID'] = d
print c
```

returns:

```
[{'ID': {...}}, {'ID': {...}}]
```

why isn't it:

```
[{'ID': a}, {'ID': b}]
```

Comment: `a` is a variable name, program can't print that.

Comment: In the loop, you're reassigning the `ID` key in `d` to `d` itself — your code makes absolutely no sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you intentionally creating dictionaries that recursively contain themselves and then asking why they display that way, or is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Why would you expect `c` to display as `[{'ID': a}, {'ID': b}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through this:

```
a = {}
b = {}
c = [a, b]
```

So far, so good.

```
for d in c:
    d['ID'] = d
```

We can unroll this to:

```
d = c[0]
d['ID'] = d
d = c[1]
d['ID'] = 1
```

And expand that to:

```
d = a
d['ID'] = d
d = b
d['ID'] = d
```

Now substitute:

```
a['ID'] = a
b['ID'] = a
```

So, let's forget about the loop for a second and look at what that does:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['ID'] = a
>>> a
{'ID': {...}}
```

In other words, you're making each `dict` recursively contain a copy of itself, under the key `ID`. How would you expect this to be printed?

So, the obvious thing to do is to try to print the whole dictionary:

```
{'ID': {'ID': {'ID': { …
```

But this would be an infinitely-long string, and Python would run out of stack space before reaching infinity. So it needs to truncate it somehow.

It can't print this:

```
{'ID': a}
```

Because `a` is just a name that happens to be bound to the `dict`, just like `d` is at the time. In fact, the loop doesn't even *know* that `a` is bound to that at the time; it knows that `d` is. But even if it *did* know, the result would be wrong. Think about this:

```
>>> e = a
>>> a = 0
>>> e
???
```

So, the obvious answer is to use an ellipsis (kind of like I did in the human-readable version) to represent "and so on".

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great explanation, and it didn't occur to me that it would make a nesting of itself (although it should have).

Answer (score 0):

a is a dictionary.

b is a dictionary.

c is a list of two dictionaries (not "two names" or "two variables").

Another socratic explanation:
If it would return `[{'ID': a}, {'ID': b}]`, values displayed as `a` and `b` would be of which type?

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the loop is doing:
    a = {}
    b = {}
    c = [a, b]

```
    for d in c:
        d['ID'] = d
```

d will be either a or b, such that

```
    a['ID'] = a
    b['ID'] = b
```

but recall a and b are {}, the dics themselves. as a result, your assigning ['ID'] to the dic itself, creating a loop. When you

```
print(c)
```

you get     `[{'ID': {...}}, {'ID': {...}}]` because the value of the key is the dic itself and not the variable representation of it, hence you get {...} to reflect the nature of the loop.
Note how after this     `a['ID']['ID']`, or even a    `['ID']['ID']['ID']['ID']`  is     `{'ID': {...}}`, because the value of the key is the dic itself, not the variable pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in c:
    d['ID'] = d
```

should be

```
c = [{'ID': d} for d in c]
```

Your code is adding the ID element to each of the dicts in `c`. That means `a = {'ID': a}` after your code has run. It contains a reference to itself.

My snippet generates a *new* dict with a property `'ID'` containing a value from `c`.